# Is it possible to plot csv data from python 2.5.1 without adding any modules

Tags: python, csv, plot, python-2.5

I have a set of data in a .csv file and i could plot it from Idle with python 2.5.1

this was the code i used.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_datafile(file_name):
    data = np.genfromtxt(file_name, dtype = float , delimiter=';', skip_header=1, usecols=(2,3), names=['Real', 'Imaginary'] )    
    return data

data= read_datafile('data.csv')
print data

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.plot(data['Real'], c='r', label='Real')
ax2.plot(data['Imaginary'], c='g', label='Imaginary')

leg = ax1.legend()
leg = ax2.legend()

plt.show()
```

Now the issue is i have the same version of python(2.5.1) for which i cant install any modules, which mean all the matplotlib and numpy wouldnt be of any use.

Is there any alternative i could plot the csv file data ?? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could use the included `Tkinter.canvas` widget, but you'd probably have to write your own plotting code.

Comment: *Why* can't you install needed modules? May be we can solve *that*?

Comment: @joel i will check more info about Tkinter.canvas, thank you.

Comment: @alko the python programme is integrated into another software, so im trying to make the optimum use of just the core for plotting.